# Assets, thumbnails not showing up and can't post new images

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

Just noticed the Thumbnails of previously published posts in the Assets modal window are not showing up anymore and I can't upload images either in new Post.

They worked fine before.

Using Assets 2.2.2 And EE 2.7.2 Cache folder is writable

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Sounds like a Javascript error - is your browser console reporting any bugs? If you're not sure, you can always shoot an email to support@pixelandtonic.com

Comment: Hi Andris, I just sent you guys a support email. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by setting the User Session Type to Cookies only.

Comment: Ah, the good old trick with user session types :)